# Tablayout bundle in fragment - null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-tablayout, android-bundle

I've used this guide here to make the activity: http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs

I have then added an AsyncTask.

I am trying to pass

Activity.java

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFrag(new ProfileFragment(), "Profile");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}

@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String JSON_STRING_GET_ID) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(JSON_STRING_GET_ID);
            JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("server_response");

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                get_nav_email = jsonChildNode.optString("email");

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("p_email", get_nav_email);
                ProfileFragment fragToProfile = new ProfileFragment();
                fragToProfile.setArguments(bundle);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

ProfileFragment.java:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View myInflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container,false);

    String p_email = getArguments().getString("p_email");
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView)myInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.tvUsername2);
    txtTitle.setText(p_email);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return myInflatedView;
}
```

Here is the error I get:

```
1779-1779/com.testing.dev.application E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.testing.dev.application, PID: 1779
                                                                              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                                  at com.testing.dev.application.fragment.ProfileFragment.onCreateView(ProfileFragment.java:43)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1177)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1025)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1545)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                                  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:664)
                                                                                  at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:731)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                                  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                                                                                  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2615)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2015)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1173)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1379)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
                                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
                                                                                  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: First of all, if you loop through an array inside onPostExecute like you are doing, you will overwrite the previous value and that doesn't seem like what you really want here. Also, you are not actually setting the fragment in view

Comment: @Eenvincible Can you tell me what you mean? I'm adding the fragment with the code setupViewPager and ViewPagerAdapter. I edited the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an approach you might want to consider here! But of course, it is upon you.

Create your ViewPagerAdapter class and inside your addFrag() method, you want to pass the value of your email like this:

```
private String emailAddress;

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager, String email) {
    super(manager);
    emailAddress = email;
}
```

Thta is the constructor of your ViewPagerAdapter which you will create inside your Activity.

Within the same ViewPagerAdapter class, you will have this method **addFrag**

```
public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    //important line here to note
    bundle.putString("email", emailAddress);

    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
}
```

Now that you are passing the email to the fragment, inside your onAttach method of the fragment, you can extract it and set as a class level variable.

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context ctx){
    super.onAttach(ctx);



    String emailAddress = getArguments().getInt("email");

    //do whatever you need here
}
```

If however you want to update the fragment without a user touching the tabs, like later on after the AsyncTask has completed, you can look into using **Events**.

You basically let the fragment you want to update subscribe to a new Event from your AsyncTask's onPostExecute method.

My favorite library is using [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

Which you can simply add to your build.gradle file like this:

```
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
```

I hope this helps and please let me know if you need any further assistance!

Comment: Thank you for all of that but that's not what I needed. I need to know why passing a string using bundle doesn't work and why I can't get it in the fragment.

Comment: Well, I think you are missing something with your code; but with your onPostExecute, you are simply creating a new instance of your fragment and setting the bundle then doing nothing with it!

Comment: On onPostExecute, it is supposed to put information into the bundle and then on the fragment page, it is supposed to get it.

Comment: Yes but you created a new Fragment instance; meaning if there is already another fragment instance running, this will not work. You need to figure out a way to notify the already loaded fragment that there is new data to display; hence my Events approach!

Comment: I will look into that. Thanks again!

Comment: I am willing to help you further if you want but then I will need to take a look at your code perhaps through gmail or somewhere

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to getString from Bundle, when Bundle is null.
Try to add checking if bundle is null:

```
String p_email = null;
if(getArguments() != null) {
    p_email = getArguments().getString("p_email");
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is checking if the argument is null or not. I want it to successfully pass the argument and then get it. I've tried doing this: bundle.putString("p_email", "Test string"); but it does not work either.

Comment: Do your tabs even change?

Comment: I mean if you comment those String, can you open fragment?

Comment: Yes, if I remove "getArguments" on the fragment page, I can open the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass arguments to the `Fragment` using `setArguments` method. Using `newInstance` method rather than the default constructor is generally recommended way to instantiate Fragments.

Refer to [this](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/using-newinstance-to-instantiate.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245408/best-practice-for-instantiating-a-new-android-fragment).